# Trouble with implementing overloaded operator

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting my overloaded `=` operator working. I have a class like this.

```
SSLColumn::SSLColumn(int n){
   m_capacity = n;
   m_data = new int[m_capacity];
   m_size = 0;
   m_start = 0;
   m_end = 0;
}
```

And my overloaded operator as of now is like this

```
const SSLColumn& SSLColumn::operator=(const SSLColumn& rhs) {
      m_capacity = rhs.m_capacity;
      m_data = new int[m_capacity];
      m_size = rhs.m_size;
      m_start = rhs.m_start;
      m_end = rhs.m_end;

      for(int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
         m_data[i] = rhs.m_data[i];

      return *this;
}
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. Is there something I am missing or not doing correctly?

Comment: You have a memory leak.

Comment: Can you please specify more "does not work" ? What are you expecting and what does not work?

Comment: m_size is not initialize

Comment: m_size is initialized. Idk why it says that. And when the overloaded operator is used, when I display, I get a bunch of random numbers. I should be getting back the actual values. Also this is just in the class, so by the time this is used, all the attributes are initialized and have a value.

Comment: You don't initialize the items in `m_data`.  Your assignment operator may be copying from an instance that has undefined values in `m_data` (a.k.a. random numbers).  Use a debugger and place a breakpoint in your assignment function.  Look at the values in `rhs.m_data` (or print them out).

Comment: _"m_size = 0;\`enter code here\`"_ This is not valid C++

Comment: you should familiarize yourself with [the Rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and you should really appreciate the importance of the Rule of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Member variable m_size is not initialize in constructor , hence for loop will not work in the overloaded operator. See this pseudo code , assuming m_size = m_ capacity:

```
class SSLColumn {
     int m_capacity;
     int m_size; 
    int* m_data ;
public:
    SSLColumn( int n);
    const SSLColumn& operator=(const SSLColumn& rhs);
};

SSLColumn::SSLColumn( int n) {
    m_capacity = m_size = n;   // <--- SEE HERE !  ( m_size need some value later
    m_data = new int[n];
}

const SSLColumn& SSLColumn::operator=(const SSLColumn& rhs) {
    if( m_data == NULL)  m_data = new int[m_capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        m_data[i] = rhs.m_data[i];

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: m_size is initialized to 0. by the time the overloaded constructor is called, m_size has a value other than 0;

Comment: @griffer98: Then the loop in the overloaded operator will happen 0 times, since it is never initialized. I edited my code slightly so that you can grasp

Comment: m_size fdoes have a value by the time I call the overloaded operator. m_size is not zero or n. When I run the program the loop actually loops, its the fact that instead of giving me the values that were copied over, it gives me numbers like im access memory that doesnt have any actual value. Other than my constructor, is there anything wrong with the code in my overloaded operator?

Comment: @griffer98:Rest seem ok but the value of m_size need to be set somewhere.